# Calling an executable with a timeout

Tags: go, command, timeout

I am trying to use the `context` package to run a binary with a 10 second timeout, as such:

```
func RunQL(file db.File, flag string) string { 
    
    // 10-second timeout for the binary to run
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "qltool", "run", "-f", file.Path, "--rootfs", file.Root, "--args", flag)
    out, err := cmd.Output()

    // check to see if our timeout was executed
    if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
        return ""
    }

    // no timeout (either completed successfully or errored)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }

    return string(out)
}
```

But for some reason, it still hangs if the process lasts longer than 10 seconds. Not sure what would be causing this, I also noticed that the documentation for the `CommandContext()` function appears to be wrong/misleading? It shows the following code:

```
func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    if err := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sleep", "5").Run(); err != nil {
        // This will fail after 100 milliseconds. The 5 second sleep
        // will be interrupted.
    }
}
```

But `CommandContext()` returns type `*Cmd` not `error` .

Comment: What OS are you running this on? Linux, MacOS & Windows behave very differently when it comes to terminating processes & especially when they're are sub-processes involved.

Comment: Its a Debian system running on WSL

Comment: On my Debian machine cancelling commands using this method (`CommandContext` and `context.WithTimeout`) works fine. The documentation's example code is correct - note that `.Run()` is called, which returns an error.

Comment: Ah, totally missed that they are calling .Run(), thanks for the info (was a long night last night :) ). Looks like the issue is with the tool/command that I am running as I experience some weirdness outside of golang just manually running the command. It runs infinitely, and can't even be killed with a ctrl-C (pressing ctrl-C brings me back to my prompt, but the process is still running as output continuously prints to the terminal even afterwards). The only way to kill it is to actually call `kill -9 <PID>`...